# How to selectively disable CSRF check in Phoenix framework

Tags: elixir, csrf, phoenix-framework, csrf-protection

I'm trying to create a Facebook Page Tab which points to my website. 
Facebook sends a HTTP POST request to the url of my website.
The problem here is that the server has a built-in CSRF check, and it returns the following error:

```
(Plug.CSRFProtection.InvalidCSRFTokenError) invalid CSRF (Cross Site  Forgery Protection) token, make sure all requests include a '_csrf_token' param or an 'x-csrf-token' header`
```

The server expects a CSRF token that Facebook can't have. So, I want to selectively disable CSRF for the path www.mywebsite.com/facebook.

How can I do it in Phoenix Framework?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The `Plug.CSRFProtection` is enabled in your router with `protect_from_forgery`. This is set by default in the `browser` pipeline. Once a plug has been added, there is no way to disable it, instead it has to be not set in the first place. You can do this by moving it out of `browser` and only including it when it is required.

```
defmodule Foo.Router do
  use Foo.Web, :router

  pipeline :browser do
    plug :accepts, ["html"]
    plug :fetch_session
    plug :fetch_flash
    #plug :protect_from_forgery - move this
  end

  pipeline :csrf do
    plug :protect_from_forgery # to here
  end

  pipeline :api do
    plug :accepts, ["json"]
  end

  scope "/", Foo do
    pipe_through [:browser, :csrf] # Use both browser and csrf pipelines

    get "/", PageController, :index
  end

  scope "/", Foo do
    pipe_through :browser # Use only the browser pipeline

    get "/facebook", PageController, :index #You can use the same controller and actions if you like
  end

end
```