# Phoenix/Elixir: CSRF with frontend application

Tags: ajax, file-upload, elixir, phoenix-framework, nuxt.js

I'm using [nuxt](/questions/tagged/nuxt) for front-end, phoenix/elixir for API server, and nginx for reverse-proxy.

I've hit the wall when I tried to make a form for uploading files.
How do I work with the `csrf`?

Comment: I posted two answers, one that disables CSRF and another that uses it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Use CSRF

CSRF provides a lot of security benefits, especially for session-based web applications, so it might make sense for you to keep using it (if you aren't using something like [auth-token](/questions/tagged/auth-token) instead). This can usually get a bit complicated in frontend SPAs, but the basic process is to:

1. Render the CSRF token (usually in a hidden field or JS variable) using [`get_csrf_token/0`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html#get_csrf_token/0) on your webpage on the initial request
2. Read the value and send it back to the server in the `X-CSRF-TOKEN` request header in your subsequent [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) calls
3. Regenerate a new CSRF token on the server after sometime and send it back in the response headers of an existing request or in the response of a dedicated request just for the token
4. Save it in your webapp for the next non-`GET` request

<sup>*(Assuming that your SPA isn't a completely separate frontend project and is atleast partially server-rendered)*</sup>

---

Here are some other resources:

- **Information Security:** [CSRF protection and Single Page Apps](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36468/csrf-protection-and-single-page-apps)
- **HexDocs:** [Plug.CSRFProtection](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.CSRFProtection.html)
- **Blog Post:** [Elixir, Phoenix and CSRF](https://www.amberbit.com/blog/2018/4/19/elixir-phoenix-csrf-token-and-gloomy-foreteller/)

Comment: I'm using cookie-session, doesn't cookie-session offer enough security?

Comment: Depends on your use-case, but the short answer is 'No'. To make things easier for SPAs, I would personally recommend to disable CSRF, and instead use auth tokens. You should explicitly send the auth token in request header for each ajax call you make.

Comment: Two ways to go: a) If it's a completely separate SPA, auth token would be the better choice. b) If the frontend is server-rendered with a few Nuxt/Vue components sprinkled at different places, then stick with CSRF.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

### Disable CSRF

If you aren't using sessions in your [phoenix-framework](/questions/tagged/phoenix-framework) API server (and using something like auth tokens, for example), the simplest option would be to [disable CSRF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32581072/1533054). You can do that by removing the [`:protect_from_forgery`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html#protect_from_forgery/2) plug from your Router pipeline:

```ex
pipeline :browser do
  plug :accepts, ["html"]
  plug :fetch_session
  plug :fetch_flash
  # plug :protect_from_forgery ## REMOVE THIS
end
```

<sup>***Note:*** SPAs generally use the `:api` pipeline, where this is excluded by default</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you're only interacting with your backend via AJAX, you can disable CSRF protection in favour of requiring a custom request header, [per OWASP's advice](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.md#use-of-custom-request-headers).